# csp-algorithm for context-free grammars

Tags: constraints, graph-algorithm, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to solve a CSP (Constraint-Satisfaction-Problem), which is based on arbitrary context-free grammars. A quick example: Let's say we have a context-free grammar with the following production rules: S->A, S->B, S->AB, A->Aa, A->a, A->aa, B->Bb, B->b, B->bb.

Now I'm looking for a word, which uses specific (sub-sequences of) production rules. For example:

```
"B->b" must be used 3 times in the whole derivation-sequence
If "S->AB" is used, it must be followed by "B->Bb"
If "S->Aa" is used, it must directly be followed by "A->a"
```

I know the problem is a CSP, but I couldnt find a specific algorithm on how to solve this. Any ideas, which (concrete) algorithm could be used? Also, I'm thinking about the right data-strucure. Should I rather use an n-Tree or an array (CYK-Table)?

Comment: Possibly irrelevant since you are likely thinking of a more complex CFG, but in your example it is impossible for `S->AB` to be used more than once since it never appears in a right-hand side. The other two constraints could be enforced by substitution; for example, replace `S->AB` with `S->ABb` to enforce that the next reduction is `B->Bb`. There is no `S->Aa`; perhaps you meant `A->Aa`, in which case the substitution would be `A->aa`.

Comment: your're right, my fault ... this was just an easy example :)